# How to fix this git error that i should have fixed [kinda fixed]

Tags: git

I get the classic

> Make sure you configure your "user.name" and "user.email"

in Git but I have already done that when I run `git config --list` I get that my `user.name` and `user.email` are set. When look in my `.gitconfig` file I see that they are configured I did not get this error last week. The editor I use is VSCode and the extensions I have for git are "Git history", "Github pull requests and issues", "gitignore" and "Gitlens - Git supercharged"

I have tried running this command in PowerShell

```
$env:GIT_CONFIG = "C:\path\to\your\gitconfig"
```

with the correct file path. If possible I would like a fix that doesn't require too much admin usage because this is a school computer and we don't have too many privileges

### Workaround

I am now just using the git-cmd.exe and running commands manually instead now this works fine for me so if anyone else has this problem I would recommend learning the command prompt

Comment: there may be an issue with the environment where `Gitlens` runs its commands -- which may differ from what you see when you open a terminal. What OS are you using ? I imagine your `.gitconfig` is defined in the standard location : `$HOME/.gitconfig` ?